# Wifite on Termux in Android device doesn't find wireless interfaces

Tags: linux, wifi, android

I try to run and start Wifite on Termux on my Android phone but received this error:

```
.               .                                                                                                                                   [+] option: targeting WPS-encrypted networks                                                                    
[+] Checking airmon-ng...                               
[!] airmon-ng did not find any wireless interfaces      
[!] Make sure your wireless device is connected         
[!] See https://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=airmon-ng for more info                                                                                                 
[!] Error: airmon-ng did not find any wireless interfaces                                                                                                               
[!] Full stack trace below                                                                                      
[!]    Traceback (most recent call last):               
[!]    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/wifite/__main__.py", line 104, in entry_point                       
[!]        wifite.start()                               
[!]    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/wifite/__main__.py", line 57, in start                              
[!]        Configuration.get_monitor_mode_interface()   
[!]    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/wifite/config.py", line 228, in get_monitor_mode_interface          
[!]        cls.interface = Airmon.ask()                 
[!]                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^                 
[!]    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/wifite/tools/airmon.py", line 300, in ask                           
[!]        raise Exception('airmon-ng did not find any wireless interfaces')                                    
[!]  Exception: airmon-ng did not find any wireless interfaces                                                                                                          
[!] Exiting
```

What can I do? I want to run Wifite.

Comment: anyways, yeah, I don't think you will be able to run airmon-ng against an android wifi stack.

Answer (score -1):

To solve this problem you shoud use wifi doungle that  support android phone   only thing you need to do is to plug it with otg
, in termux reastart wlan and every thing is run ok